# tabbar can't display completely

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I have an uiviewcontroller,and add a tabbar,my code like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:Originalviewcontroller];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:differentviewcontroller];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:tradeviewcontroller];
    UITabBarController *uitabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    uitabbarcontroller.delegate = self;
    uitabbarcontroller.viewControllers = viewControllersArray;  
    [originalviewcontroller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"123" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Original.png"] tag:1];
    [differentviewcontroller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"456" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Different.png"] tag:2];
    [tradeviewcontroller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"789" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Trade.png"] tag:3];

    [self.view addSubview:uitabbarcontroller.view];  
}
```

it runs well,but my title can't display,just display the images.it seems the tabbar don't display completely.

In IB,I have set Botton Bar is "Tab Bar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you set the title and image on UITabBarController is wrong here :

```
    [originalViewController.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"123" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Original.png"] tag:1];
```

This should work. I have tried it myself on XCode.

Solution :

```
    originalViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"123";
    originalViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Original.png"];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:Originalviewcontroller];
```

Comment: Try setting controller title. Something like  originalviewcontroller.title = @"123"; what is the result?

Comment: what's the meaning of "originalviewcontroller.title = @"123""?I tried,but can't solve my problem,the result is the same as before

Comment: I was just trying to understand your situation. What if you try to set the title before you add the controller into the array.

Something like :

    originalViewController.title = @"123";
    NSMutableArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:originalViewController];